# SharePoint 2010 Powershell unable to get the title of SSRS Report viewer webpart

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

In SharePoint2010, I dragged and dropped two webparts on the page "Performance point filter(PPS)" webpart and "SSRS Report viewer" webpart. I am trying to connect the two webparts programmatically.

The issue is that with the help of PowerShell script I tried to print the ID and the title of two webparts on the page, and to my surprise only the Title of the PPS filter webpart is displayed, but not the title of the "SSRS Report viewer" webpart, only its ID is getting printed. Any idea why?

Below is my powershell script:-

```
$siteURL = "http://mysite/test
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteURL)
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
$page = $web.GetFile("Pages/testpage.aspx")
 if($page.CheckOutStatus -eq "None")
{
$page.CheckOut()
}
 $egrWpsCount=0
 $wpm = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("Pages/testpage.aspx",  [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
foreach($webpart in $wpm.WebParts)
{
$webpart.title
$webpart.ID
$egrWpsCount++
}
"WebpartCount: "+$egrWpsCount
$page.CheckIn("testpage")   
$web.Close()
$site.Close()
```

I need to access the title of SSRS report viewer webpart programatically, so that I can connect the two webparts.Otherwise, while establishing connection programtically I am getting below error:-
*SSRSeportWebParts Error : ReportViewerWebPart is not found*

Thanks

Comment: It should be `$webpart.Title` instead of `$webpart.title`